# Redux Observable: How to use takeUntil inside flatMap?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a flatMap with the purpose of emitting two actions:

```js
export default function searchForPartner(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(statusActions.SEARCH_FOR_PARTNER)
    .filter(() => store.getState().user.signedIn)
    .delay(2000)
    .flatMap(() => [
      carouselActions.slideTo(config.CAROUSEL_SLIDES.CONFIRM_CHAT),
      statusActions.foundPerson(),
    ])
    .takeUntil(action$.ofType(carouselActions.TAP_CANCEL))
};
```

However, the `takeUntil` is in the wrong spot. It is cancelling the whole epic when `TAP_CANCEL` is emitted. Instead, I only want it to cancel the emitting of the actions inside `flatMap`.  How would I do this?

=== UPDATE ===

I fooled around with it and this seems to work? But I don't like that there are 2 timers:

```js
export default function searchForPartner(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(statusActions.SEARCH_FOR_PARTNER)
    .filter(() => store.getState().user.signedIn)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.merge(
        Observable.timer(2000)
          .map(() => carouselActions.slideTo(config.CAROUSEL_SLIDES.CONFIRM_CHAT)),
        Observable.timer(2000)
          .map(() => statusActions.foundPerson())
      )
      .takeUntil(action$.ofType(carouselActions.TAP_CANCEL))
    )
};
```

Comment: So you don't want to emit the actions if a `TAP_CANCEL` is received during the 2000 delay?

Comment: hm I want to cancel the execution of everything inside `flatMap` if `TAP_CANCEL` is received. I think I might have the `delay(2000)` in the wrong spot

Comment: @cartant updated the question with an ugly solution I threw together

Comment: Correct, I don't want the side effects of `carouselActions.slideTo` and `statusActions.foundPerson` to happen when `TAP_CANCEL` has been called before the 2 second delay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to isolate the `delay` and the `takeUntil` into the inner Observable, the most important thing being that you start the `delay` timer, then `takeUntil` it, so that if someone cancels it, you are for sure listening--if your `delay` was outside, you wouldn't be listening for the cancel action yet! This is subtle, but important to understand why.

```
export default function searchForPartner(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(statusActions.SEARCH_FOR_PARTNER)
    .filter(() => store.getState().user.signedIn)
    .flatMap(() =>
      Observable.of(
        carouselActions.slideTo(config.CAROUSEL_SLIDES.CONFIRM_CHAT),
        statusActions.foundPerson()
      )
        .delay(2000)
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(carouselActions.TAP_CANCEL))
    );
}
```

You may also want to consider using `switchMap` instead of `flatMap` (aka `mergeMap`) because if another `SEARCH_FOR_PARTNER` comes in while the previous is still waiting, you'll have a queue of them lined up. Probably not want you want, but you'll have to make that call.

Comment: wow nice! is there a book / site where you learned this stuff? the rx docs are pretty crappy

Comment: I learned mostly through experience and I was on the core team previously. Which docs are you reading? I recommend reading this start to finish if you haven't: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html Another thing that helps is to basically build a "RxJS lite clone". Understand how it works which will make it less magical hehe :) https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87

Comment: Awesome I'll take a look! Thanks a lot

Comment: RxJs error:  TypeError: (0 , _rxjs.of)(...).delay is not a function